# hide an element if a specific string is not on the web page

Tags: jquery

I want to hide a div with the class '.femanager_moduleSysDmailNewsletter' if the string "Mitgliedsnummer" is found on the current web page. Right now the div is always hidden. 
This is what I tried:

```
$(function () {
    if ("p:contains(Mitgliedsnummer)") {
        $(".femanager_moduleSysDmailNewsletter").hide();
    } else {
        $(".femanager_moduleSysDmailNewsletter").show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the `length` of `$(selector)`

`if($(selector))` will always be truthy since an object is always returned regardless if selector matches are found or not

in your case you have ignored the `$()` part and are simply checking `if(StringValue)` which is also truthy so long as the string isn't empty

Try changing

```
 if ("p:contains(Mitgliedsnummer)") {
```

To

```
 if ($("p:contains(Mitgliedsnummer)").length) {
```

Comment: perfect for me.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `"p:contains(Mitgliedsnummer)"` is simply a string and not a jQuery selector, so it will always evaluate to true. What you want is to convert it to a jQuery selector, and then checking its length. A falsy value (`0`) will mean that no element matches your selector, while a truth value (`1` or more) means at least one `<p>` element contains your text of interest.

Doing this will work:

```
if ($("p:contains('Mitgliedsnummer')").length) {
    $(".femanager_moduleSysDmailNewsletter").hide();
} else {
    $(".femanager_moduleSysDmailNewsletter").show();
}
```

```js
$(function() {

  var containsText = $('p:contains("Mitgliedsnummer")');
  if (containsText.length) {
    $(".femanager_moduleSysDmailNewsletter").hide();
  } else {
    $(".femanager_moduleSysDmailNewsletter").show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="femanager_moduleSysDmailNewsletter">
  Target div to be toggled
</div>

<p>Mitgliedsnummer</p>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
<p>foo bar</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you typing like `if("p:contains(Mitgliedsnummer)")` actually this is dose not return any Boolean value it is a selector. Try following way:

```
$(function () {
    if($('p').is(':contains("Mitgliedsnummer")')) {
        $(".femanager_moduleSysDmailNewsletter").hide();
    } else {
        $(".femanager_moduleSysDmailNewsletter").show();
    }
});
```